# What is the JSDoc type for document.getElementById('myID') and a jQuery Element?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to document my functions with JSDoc syntax.

```
/**
 * 
 * My Description
 * 
 * @param {JQuery|???} input
 * @returns {JQuery}
 */
function foo(input){
    return $('selector');
}
```

The above function accepts a single argument which can be either a JQuery object, or an element returned by `document.getElementById`.

**What is the valid JSDoc type for the return value of `getElementById`?**

For example, the following are both valid:

```
foo($('#input'));
foo(document.getElementById('input'));
```

Also, where can I find this out in future?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`getElementById` will always return a subtype of [**Element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element). In the case of an HTML document, `HTMLElement` will be more appropriate

```
document.getElementById('some-anchor').constructor //HTMLAnchorElement
document.getElementById('some-div').constructor //HTMLDivElement
```

In all cases, `document.getElementById('some-element') instanceof HTMLElement` will, IMHO, return true

Answer (score 5):

Whilst technically the return value of `getElementById` is `object`, the documentation should help the developer to know what it is.

I'd personally go with `Element` but there is no indications as to what you should use.

Comment: Uppercase `Element` maybe - it's a constructor?

Answer (score 4):

`HTMLElement` or `any` can be used in your example.

```
/**
 * @param {JQuery|HTMLElement} input
 * @returns {JQuery}
 */
function foo(input){
    return $('selector');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario `Element` is what seems to be the most suitable, but generally speaking you want to be as accurante as your code permits.

For instance, using recent advanced IDEs, using `Element` won't provide autocompletion for attributes such as `disabled` or `readOnly`. I find it useful to use, for instance, the `HTMLInputElement` @type instead.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` will also return a javascript object.

in jQuery -> $('#input') just wraps the element with an id of input into a jQuery object so that jQuery methods can be applied on it.

So in both cases the type is an object.

```
var x = document.getElementById('input');

alert(typeof x);// object
```

Comment: but that's also true with `typeof new Date()`, however putting `object` everywhere (most things are objects in js) doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Prisoner - I have to agree with you on that. i was just clarifying that both will return an object. Element would be accurate.